# What does it mean by "label = (Label)tableLayoutPanel.Controls[i];"?

Tags: c#, controls, label, tablelayoutpanel

It is a partial code of a mind game in windows form. My question is  why do I've to set the "Label" of tableLayoutPanel1.Controls into the local variable label? Also Why it is put inside an if condition?

```
Label label;
int randomNumber;
for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    if (tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i] is Label)
       label = (Label)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i];
    else
       continue;
}
```

Comment: Title: It casts the i th control in the TFP to Label. The result is either a Label or an exception. The if prevents the exception. It is a good idea to create a loval variable which has all references and casts resolved as it will be faster to process and easier to read.

Comment: Ask the author maybe? The loop search for `Label` inside `TableLayoutPanel` using sub-optimal `is/cast` (`as/null` check is better usually), the `continue` *imply* there suppose to be a code after label is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: `(Label)` is [explicit type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) and `if` with [`is`-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) make it safe to do.

**Longer answer**: Here is commented and cleaned version of your code snippet (removed unnecessary `randomNumber` variable and `else`-branch:

```
// Declare variable label, which has type Label. It's value is null here.
Label label;
// Loop as many rounds than there are items in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls - collection
for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    // When looping, i has value 0,1,2,3 depending on for loop round
    // Check if tableLayoutPanel1.Controls-collection has item at position i
    // which has type compatible with Label. C# operator "is" is used.
    if (tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i] is Label)
    {  
       // It is safe to make explicit type conversion to Label 
       // and set reference to label-variable
       label = (Label)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls[i];
    }
}
```

Result of the snippet is that label variable has reference to last item in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls-collection which has type compatible with Label.